# Crawling and parsing meteorological data from the web into R

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, r

I am interested in collecting directly into R data published by the Mexican Met-office.  The data pieces are spread through several URLs, but one can start [here](http://smn.cna.gob.mx/emas/).  There I can get the names and locations of all stations and links to locations where the details of each station are displayed separately.  At that last location there is a button that takes me to a table with whatever sensor information is available.

I have done some crawling and parsing of all this with the XML library, but it is my first time doing this, so it is a very crude approach.  I wonder if any of you would be interested in help me to improve the brute force code that I manage to assemble. I would like to have one table of stations information including geo-reference, and another with the sensor data. Ideally they should be suitable to merge. Hope the post is not too large or imposing, but certainly I hope to get help in learning about crawling and parsing for data like these!

How should this have been properly done?

```
library ("XML")
library("dplyr")

# All stations in a general catalog
# By trial and error I found that what I want was in tables 5 and 6 
# of the XML tree.
url.conagua.base <- "http://smn.cna.gob.mx/emas/"
url.estaciones <- paste(url.conagua.base, "catalogoa.html", sep="")
pagina.conagua <- htmlParse(url.estaciones)

datos_EMAs <- readHTMLTable(pagina.conagua, which = 5, header = T, 
                            stringsAsFactors = F)
str(datos_EMAs)
head(datos_EMAs)
datos_EMAs$NOMBRE

datos_ESIMEs <- readHTMLTable(pagina.conagua, which = 6, header = T, 
                              stringsAsFactors = F)
str(datos_ESIMEs)
head(datos_EMAs)

# I found some character were displayed bad, so I forced UTF-8
Encoding(datos_EMAs$"Latitud (Norte)") <-"UTF-8"
Encoding(datos_EMAs$"Longitud (Oeste)") <-"UTF-8"
Encoding(datos_EMAs$ESTADO) <-"UTF-8"
Encoding(datos_EMAs$NOMBRE) <-"UTF-8"

Encoding(datos_ESIMEs$"Latitud (Norte)") <-"UTF-8"
Encoding(datos_ESIMEs$"Longitud (Oeste)") <-"UTF-8"
Encoding(datos_ESIMEs$ESTADO) <-"UTF-8"
Encoding(datos_ESIMEs$NOMBRE) <-"UTF-8"

# To convert coordinates to decimal degrees created this simple function
divide_coord <- function (x)
{
  numeros.separados <- as.double(unlist(strsplit(x, "[º\'\"]")))
  grad.dec <- sum(numeros.separados / c(1, 60, 3600))
} 

# Applied the coordinate function to stations of kind EMA
datos_EMAs$lat.dec <- sapply(datos_EMAs$"Latitud (Norte)", divide_coord, USE.NAMES = F)
datos_EMAs$lon.dec <- sapply(datos_EMAs$"Longitud (Oeste)", divide_coord, USE.NAMES = F)

# Same for stations kind ESIMEs
datos_ESIMEs$lat.dec <- sapply(datos_ESIMEs$"Latitud (Norte)", divide_coord, USE.NAMES = F)
datos_ESIMEs$lon.dec <- sapply(datos_ESIMEs$"Longitud (Oeste)", divide_coord, USE.NAMES = F)

# Put the two kind of stations together (
datos_EMAs$tipo <- "EMA"
datos_ESIMEs$tipo <- "ESIME"
estaciones.todas - as.data.frame(bind_rows(datos_EMAs, datos_ESIMEs))
```

This first block of information seems to me pretty straightforward. But from here on I stumbled a lot!

```
# Get the links to individual station pages
link.1 <- xpathApply(pagina.conagua, "//a[@href]", xmlGetAttr, "href")
link.1 <- grep('*catalogo*',unlist(link.1),value=T)
link.1 <- substr(link.1,3,nchar(link.1))
url.em <- paste(url.conagua.base, link.1, sep="")

# Get the link pointing to sensor data every 10 minutes. However if 
# the end of the file name is change from "10M.TXT", I can get data at 
# time frames of 60 mins or 1 day: "60M.TXT" and "24H.TXT")
# Prepare a table for this links annotated with station name and lat lon
estaciones <- data.frame(nombre=character(length(url.em)),
                         lat=character(length(url.em)),
                         lon=character(length(url.em)),
                         link=character(length(url.em)),
                         stringsAsFactors = F)

# Go through the list of stations to recover links to sensor data
for (i in 1:length(url.em))
{
  # Get station name and lat, lon if possible for reference
  pagina.em <- htmlTreeParse(url.em[i], useInternalNodes = T, validate=T)
  text.head <- xpathSApply(pagina.em, "//tr", xmlValue)

  # I found a problem with some pages having empty //tr tags
  if (length (text.head[grep("Nombre:", text.head)]) > 1)
    text.head <- text.head[-1]

  # Look for the bits of information that I want, first: name, lat and lon
  estacion <- unlist(strsplit(text.head[grep("Nombre:", text.head)], "[\r\n]"))[3]
  lat <- unlist(strsplit(text.head[grep("Latitud:", text.head)], "[\r\n]"))[3]
  lon <- unlist(strsplit(text.head[grep("Longitud:", text.head)], "[\r\n]"))[3]    

  # I found some variation in the formation of pages so I tried to
  # deal with the cases that I found by brute force
  if (is.null(estacion)) 
  {
    text.head <- xpathSApply(pagina.em, "//td", xmlValue)
    estacion <- text.head[10]
    lat <- text.head[12]
    lon <- text.head[14]
  }

  # Record 145 appeared to me a very badly formed html
  if (i == 145)
  {
    text <- getNodeSet(pagina.em, "//div")[[3]]
    text <- strsplit(xmlAttrs(text), "<td>")
    estacion <- strsplit(text[[2]][[5]], "<")[[1]][[1]]
    lat <- text[[2]][[7]]
  }

  # Make sure the characters are UTF-8
  if (!is.null(estacion)) Encoding(estacion) <- "UTF-8" else estacion <- substr(url.em[i], 37, nchar(url.em[i])-5)
  if (!is.null(lat)) Encoding(lat) <-"UTF-8" else lat <- ""
  if (!is.null(lon)) Encoding(lon) <-"UTF-8" else lon <- ""  

  # Put data found in previously prepared data.frame
  estaciones$nombre[i] <- estacion
  estaciones$lat[i] <- lat
  estaciones$lon[i] <- lon

  # Now I deal with the links.  Again I found variation in the pages
  # html structure, so I dealt with the cases found. Pure brute force!!
  top <- xmlRoot(pagina.em)
  contiene.link <- top[["body"]][["center"]][[4]]
  if (is.null(contiene.link))
    data.char <- "" else 
    data.char <- as.character(unlist(xmlAttrs(contiene.link)))    

  if (is.null(contiene.link) | is.na(pmatch ("self.location.href", data.char)))
  {
    contiene.link <- top[["body"]][["center"]][[5]]
    if (is.null(contiene.link))
      data.char <- "" else 
      data.char <- as.character(unlist(xmlAttrs(contiene.link)))    
    if(is.null(contiene.link) | is.na(pmatch ("self.location.href", data.char)))
    {
      contiene.link <- top[["body"]][["center"]][[3]][[3]]
      if (is.null(contiene.link))
        data.char <- "" else 
        data.char <- as.character(unlist(xmlAttrs(contiene.link)))
      if(is.null(contiene.link) | is.na(pmatch ("self.location.href", data.char)))
        contiene.link <- top[["body"]][["center"]][[2]][[1]][[1]][[5]]
    }
  }

  link.estacion <- xmlAttrs(contiene.link)[[1]]
  estaciones$link[i] <- strsplit(link.estacion, "[()']")[[1]][3]
}
```

My final block collects sensor data and assembles a `data.frame` with all the numbers:

```
# Read table of sensor data with 10 mins records for each station
for (i in 1:length(estaciones$nombre))
{
  url.datos <- estaciones$link[i]
  pagina.datos <- htmlTreeParse(url.datos, useInternalNodes = T)
  top <- xmlRoot(pagina.datos)
  pagina.datos <- xmlValue(top[["body"]][["p"]][["text"]])[1]
  datos.clim <- read.table(text = pagina.datos, quote="\"",header=T,  
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=4, fill=T)
  datos.clim <- cbind(estacion = 
                        rep(estaciones$nombre[i], 
                            length=length(datos.clim[,1])),
                        link = 
                        rep(estaciones$link[i], 
                            length=length(datos.clim[,1])),
                        datos.clim, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  if (i==1){ 
    datos.lista <- list(datos.clim)
  }else
    datos.lista <- c(datos.lista, list(datos.clim))
}

# Give name of station to each data.frames in the list and
# stacks all the data.frames in a single one!!!!
names(datos.lista) <- estaciones$nombre
big.table <- as.data.frame(bind_rows (datos.lista))
```

Comment: You can directly provide the encoding when reading the `html`. Use e.g. `htmlParse(url.estaciones, encoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: I would have used `dplyr` and `rvest` but your solution is far from inelegant. It gets the job done quite well. I'm out of spare time today, but some of the `dplyr` I would have used I put into a non-complete answer (please don't accept it) below.